# How to fix webkit-fake-url mean?

Tags: javascript, html, safari

When you try to copy and paste to Safari web browser the browser inserts `webkit-fake-url`.

In Chrome, you could do `getAsFile()` on the clipboard data to read the image. Can you do something like that with Safari?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, it's impossible to access the pasted file's contents in Safari at the moment.

As a workaround, you can detect that faux protocol and display a message to the user informing them that it doesn't work when using their particular browser (and perhaps show a normal upload control).

Comment: Most editors silently strip the image (e.g. Google Docs). Seems like the less obtrusive route.

Comment: @SeanMahan I think it would be more astonishing to paste an image and it doesn't appear. I think informing the user it's not supported is useful.