# UIWebView contenteditable access to pasted images

Tags: ios, uiwebview, contenteditable

Before marking as duplicate, please see last paragraph below.

I'm using a UIWebView in my email client app for iOS 8 (don't need older version support).  I'm using contenteditable to support sending HTML emails.  If a user opens Safari and selects an image and selects Copy, then switches over to my app and selects Paste, it inserts the image and everything looks good, but when they send the email has an img like this:

```
<img src="webkit-fake-url://1188d962-2e07-4396-88d1-666f54ee1b3a/imagejpeg">
```

I'd like to access the image data (UIImage would be great) so I can cover the URL to a cid: type URL and send the image data to my server so it can work like a normal attached inline image in an HTML email.

I notice the GMail app has the same issue, and doesn't support this either, so maybe it just isn't possible.

**Not a dupe:**
The access in my case doesn't need to be JavaScript, it can be Objective-C/Swift if that helps, so not really a duplicate of these other questions which are limited to JavaScript and don't have really good answers anyway:

[Javascript webkit-fake-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108459/javascript-webkit-fake-url)

[How to fix webkit-fake-url mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680807/how-to-fix-webkit-fake-url-mean)

Comment: Hi! Did you found solution?